# Cannot connect to database inside a function php

Tags: php, function

i have a php file in which im connecting to my database and retrieve my values,

```
<?
  $dbconn = mysqli_connect(..,..,..);
  $query = ...
  $result = ...
  ...
?>
```

everything's great with this code, but when im putting the block inside a php function, i cant retreive my values (the call to the procedure couldnt be performed), im trying this:

```
<?
     $dbconn = mysqli_connect(...,...,...);
     function drawTable()
    {
       $query = ...
       $result = ...
       ....
    }
   drawTable();


?>
```

Comment: You need to define $query and $result out of the function?

Comment: no the query must be inside the function, coz every time i call the function, will go and retreive my data from the database

Comment: If you'd shown the code rather than '...' then we'd have known it was a scope problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is because in the function scope, the external variables are not visible.

You can reach the $dbconn variable by making it global, or by passing it as an argument.

```
global $dbconn; 
$dbconn = mysqli_connect(...,...,...);
function drawTable()
{
   global $dbconn;
   $query = ...
   $result = ...
   ....
}
drawTable();
```

or

```
 $dbconn = mysqli_connect(...,...,...);
 function drawTable($dbconn)
{
   $query = ...
   $result = ...
   ....
}
drawTable($dbconn);
```

Comment: They are not working, let me know if u need me to post some code, thanks alot

Comment: Try to get more clues by replacing die("Could not perform select query - " . mysqli_error()) with die("Could not perform select query :" . var_export($query,true)) because your query building may be affected by the function scope if you are using other variables to build it.

Comment: Also add the code error_reporting(E_ALL || E_STRICT) in order to ensure that you are catching all PHP errors, like an unset variable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring the conn globally, you can declare it on another php file, and then include it inside your function as an alternative.

in conn.php

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect(..,..,..);
```

in your function .php

```
function somefunction()
{
  include('/dir/to/conn.php');
  $query = ...
  $result = ...
}
```

from here on, you can then use your conn to every function, but you have to include it on every function that uses the connection. If you need to change your connection params, you can just go and change it through conn.php. you would not need to go through all functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `$dbconn` variable inside the function then it will fail since it's not in the correct scope. Pass in the `$dbconn` variable to the function so it can use it.

Comment: They are not working, let me know if u need me to post some code, thanks alot

Comment: More code would help. Post the updated code so we can see what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Way 1: access the global `$dbconn`.

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect(...,...,...);
function drawTable()
{
    global $dbconn;
    $query = ...
    $result = ...
    ....
}
drawTable();
```

Way 2: pass `$dbconn` as a parameter.

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect(...,...,...);
function drawTable($dbconn)
{
    $query = ...
    $result = ...
    ....
}
drawTable($dbconn);
```

Comment: They are not working, let me know if u need me to post some code, thanks alot

Comment: I have this code :
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$query)or die("Could not  perform select query - " . mysqli_error());

and the error  i get is : Could not perform select query -

Comment: without the function part ( as i described in my post ) my query's working great, but when im calling  it inside my function nothing retreived

Comment: Please post your whole code. And use `mysqli_error($dbconn)`;